# How do I match the file name from different directories and replace the partial filename with the actual filename?

Tags: python, file, io

So I have a slightly complicated issue that I need some help with :(

In Directory 1, I have the filenames as follows:

> 00HFP.mp4
> 0AMBV.mp4
> 2D5GN.mp4
> 3HVKR.mp4
> 3IJGQ.mp4

In Directory 2, I did some processing to the mp4s and got some output files:

> _0HFP.usd
> _AMBV.usd
> _D5GN.usd
> _HVKR.usd
> _IJGQ.usd

For some reason, the programme I'm using replaces the first number/character with an underscore for some files. Other files are generally left alone. But I need the filenames to match :( How do I do a mass renaming (over 500 files) based on this partial naming using python script? So like for example: **_0HFP.usd** should become **00HFP.usd** since there's a 00HFP.mp4 file in Directory 1.

Please help :( Thank you!

Trying this (as suggested by Corralien): but still doesn't work for me :(

```
dir1 = pathlib.Path('./mnt/d/Downloads/Charades_v1_480/charades_18Jan/done/')
dir2 = pathlib.Path('./mnt/d/Downloads/Charades_v1_480/charades_18Jan_anim/pt-charades-output/')

print('i am here')

for f1 in dir1.glob('*.mp4'):
    print(f1)
    f2 = dir2 / f'_{f1.stem[1:]}.usd'
    if f2.exists():
        f2.rename(dir2 / f'{f1.stem}.usd')
```

Comment: Is only the first character and the extension that change?

Comment: "there's a 00HFP.usd file in Directory 1."? Do you mean 00HFP.mp4?

Comment: Can you share the code? I often do this sort of thing at the linux command line.

Comment: @DavidA how do you do it at cmd line?

Comment: @MeganDarcy this is one way: `for i in ``ls *.mp4``; do  mv ${i} ${i%.*4}".usd"; done`  (only one back apostrophe for the ls *.mp4 statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the following directories:

```
Dir1
├── 00HFP.mp4
├── 0AMBV.mp4
├── 2D5GN.mp4
├── 3HVKR.mp4
└── 3IJGQ.mp4
Dir2
├── _0HFP.usd
├── _AMBV.usd
├── _D5GN.usd
├── _HVKR.usd
└── _IJGQ.usd
```

Try:

```
import pathlib

dir1 = pathlib.Path('./Dir1')
dir2 = pathlib.Path('./Dir2')

for f1 in dir1.glob('*.mp4'):
    f2 = dir2 / f'_{f1.stem[1:]}.usd'
    if f2.exists():
        f2.rename(dir2 / f'{f1.stem}.usd')
```

After processing:

```
Dir1
├── 00HFP.mp4
├── 0AMBV.mp4
├── 2D5GN.mp4
├── 3HVKR.mp4
└── 3IJGQ.mp4
Dir2
├── 00HFP.usd
├── 0AMBV.usd
├── 2D5GN.usd
├── 3HVKR.usd
└── 3IJGQ.usd
```

Comment: trying this, but seems like it doesn't enter the for loop: I added a print after the for f1 in ....... ()   but it doesn't print it out :(

Comment: You have to replace Dir1 and Dir2 by your real paths. What is the absolute path of your directories?

Comment: added in my code at the top in the post :)

Comment: Easy :-) Remove leading dots from dir1 and dir2 else they will be considered as relative paths.